# How to delete all devices from Azure IoT Hub using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I tried to delete devices using RemoveDeciceAsync method through a loop after retrieving all devices using GetDevicesAsync method. But this deletion process throws exception sometimes for some devices. Please note that the exception is not always thrown. How can I clear all the devices from IoT hub using .Net SDK?
Here is the source code to delete device:
[image: Source code to delete devices]

Here is the exception screenshot.
[image: Here is the image of the exception]

Comment: I would help if you'd edit your question to show your code and the error message

Comment: Updated the question. Can you please check now?

Comment: @user1814131, I was unable to reproduce this error. Would it be possible that you're having some device still connected to Azure IoT Hub when you try to delete them all?

Comment: I think the answer is no and I'm pretty much confident about it. (I'm the only one who is working on it and it is not available for others to use)

Comment: Can you delete devices in [Device Explorer](https://github.com/fsautomata/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer/doc/how_to_use_device_explorer.md)?

Comment: I can't delete using device explorer.

Comment: @user1814131 What's the SharedAccessKeyName value in your IoT hub connection string?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without the error but instead of using a loop with RemoveDeviceAsync the SDK provides a batch remove with force remove option.

RemoveDevices2Async(IEnumerable, Boolean, CancellationToken);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager

Comment: I've updated the question with the error. I'll try your approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Shachar, you need to use the RemoveDevices2Async API.
In order to guarantee the service availability, IoT Hub throttles the number of operations for each compute unit. You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) that the CRUD operations are throttled beyond 100/min.
The RemoveDevice**s**2Async API removes devices in bulk and one call counts for one operation only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iot_hub_connectionString);

var deviceTwins = new List<Twin>();
var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", int.MaxValue);
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
    deviceTwins.AddRange(page);
}

var devicesToDelete = deviceTwins.Select(t => { return new Device(t.DeviceId); });
var opResult = await registryManager.RemoveDevices2Async(devicesToDelete);
```